# QGIS 3.26 Layer from Image server disappears after panning/zooming

Tags: qgis

I've connected to an ARCGIS Image server using the ArcGIS ImageServer Connector plugin on QGIS 3.26

As soon as I pan/zoom the image disappears in the viewer and never returns. I've tried using QGIS 3.16 and it works fine.

Is this because that plugin is not supported on QGIS 3.26?